# Reactjs - Higher Order Component unmount not working correctly

Tags: reactjs

I created a HOC to listen for clicks outside its wrapped component, so that the wrapped component can listen and react as needed.

The HOC looks like this :

```
const addOutsideClickListener = (WrappedComponent) => {

    class wrapperComponent extends React.Component {

        componentDidMount() {
            console.log('*** component did MOUNT called ***');
            document.addEventListener('click', this._handleClickOutside.bind(this), true);
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            console.log('*** component will UNMOUNT called ***');
            document.removeEventListener('click', this._handleClickOutside.bind(this), true);
        }

        _handleClickOutside(e) {
            const domNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);

            if ((!domNode || !domNode.contains(e.target))) {

                this.wrapped.handleClickOutside();
            }
        }

        render() {

            return (
                <WrappedComponent
                    ref={(wrapped) => { this.wrapped = wrapped }}
                    {...this.props}
                />
            );
        }
    }

    return wrapperComponent;
}
```

It works fine... most of the time.

When the wrapped component is unmounted, the method "componentWillUnmount" gets called, but "removeEventListener" continues to listen for events, and so I get error messages 
"Uncaught Error: findDOMNode was called on an unmounted component."

Any ideas what could be causing this ?

Comment: see this: https://gist.github.com/Restuta/e400a555ba24daa396cc when you use "bind" a new function reference is made so technically you're trying to remove a different function

Comment: thanks ! making this change creates a new problem - i now get this error on every click everywhere "Uncaught Error: Element appears to be neither ReactComponent nor DOMNode"

Comment: I posted a new question so that the correct answer here will get credit. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41740360/reactjs-higher-order-component-unmount-not-working-correctly-part-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to constructor:

```
this._handleClickOutside = this._handleClickOutside.bind(this)
```

and then do this:

```
componentDidMount() {
            document.addEventListener('click', this._handleClickOutside, true);
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            document.removeEventListener('click', this._handleClickOutside, true);
        }
```

Comment: BUT this solution now throws an error, b/c document.addEventListener binds the callback to 'document'...

Comment: what is the error ? it's actually another error, in your code you were not removing the event listener to the function that added, you were creating new function, can you type here what's the error in the console ?

Comment: The problem is that document.addEventListener automatically binds the callback of this._handleClickOutside to 'document'. So even though i bind to the component in the constructor, inside the callback, const domNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this); ends up being called on 'document'... this seems to be a well-known mess : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler

Comment: then try to remove the line in the constructor... it's another issue by the way! and keep both of document.addEventListener('click', this._handleClickOutside, true); and this  document.removeEventListener('click', this._handleClickOutside, true);

Comment: actually I couldn't find what is the true, try it like that    document.addEventListener('click', this._handleClickOutside) and  document.removeEventListener('click', this._handleClickOutside);

Answer (score 3):

The reason why your `removeEventListener` is not working is because you are trying to remove a *newly* created function. The same applies for `addEventListener`. These are two completely difference functions and have no reference to each other whatsoever.

You have to bind your method `_handleClickOutside` so React knows there exactly one version of it. You do that by binding it in the constructor with

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this._handleClickOutside.bind(this);
}
```

or auto bind it with ES6 arrow methodology

```
 _handleClickOutside = (e) => { ... }
```

Now you pass the binded method to your eventlisteners with

```
 document.addEventListener('click', this._handleClickOutside, true);
```

and respectively the remove listener.

Comment: OK tried your suggestion, now getting "Uncaught Error: Element appears to be neither ReactComponent nor DOMNode " on every click.

Comment: This is a new question I think, so I put it here:

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41740360/reactjs-higher-order-component-unmount-not-working-correctly-part-2