# Reactjs - Higher Order Component / findDOMNode not working correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a HOC to listen for clicks outside its wrapped component, so that the wrapped component can listen and react as needed.

The HOC looks like this :

```
const addOutsideClickListener = (WrappedComponent) => {

    class wrapperComponent extends React.Component {

        constructor() {
            super();
            this._handleClickOutside.bind(this);
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            document.addEventListener('click', this._handleClickOutside, true);
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            document.removeEventListener('click', this._handleClickOutside, true);
        }

        _handleClickOutside(e) {

            // 'this' here refers to document ???
            const domNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);

            if ((!domNode || !domNode.contains(e.target))) {

                this.wrapped.handleClickOutside();
            }
        }

        render() {

            return (
                <WrappedComponent
                    ref={(wrapped) => { this.wrapped = wrapped }}
                    {...this.props}
                />
            );
        }
    }

    return wrapperComponent;
}
```

Whenever I click anywhere, I get the error "Uncaught Error: Element appears to be neither ReactComponent nor DOMNode" on the _handleOutsideClick callback.

Any ideas what could be causing this ?

---

Update:

OK so the source of the error is that "this" inside _handleClickOutside is now referring to 'document', which is what is expected 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler

This looks to be an absolute mess - it seems I can either bind the event correctly but then not be able to unbind it, or I can unbind it correctly but the binding method will throw an error...

Answer (score 1):

Try using this -

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this._handleClickOutsideRef = this._handleClickOutside.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener('click', this._handleClickOutsideRef, true);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.removeEventListener('click', this._handleClickOutsideRef, true);
    }
```

Comment: In fact, this removes ALL click bindings on the component, which doesn't help. I just need to remove the binding in question...

Comment: **A new function reference is created after .bind() is called**

Check out my updated solution

Answer (score 0):

Binding has to be done like this -

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this._handleClickOutside = this._handleClickOutside.bind(this);
}
```

or use arrow function for `_handleClickOutside`.

```
_handleClickOutside = (e) => {

    // 'this' here refers to document ???
    const domNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);

    if ((!domNode || !domNode.contains(e.target))) {

        this.wrapped.handleClickOutside();
    }

  }
```